# Restart mysql service by Plesk Schedule Task

Tags: linux, cron, plesk

I need to execude a schedule task by Plesk.

I've create a schedule job to restart mysql service.

[image]

The result of this task is this:
[image]

Interactive authentication required is the output error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only with system users like *root* or *mysql*. Unfortunately it's not possible to choose it from subscription's scheduled tasks menu. You can choose what system user to use for executing cron task only when creating task via:

*Home > Tools & Settings > Scheduled Tasks*

[Screenshot of this menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/078mK.png)